# To join two text files with same column entries and some same strings from columns

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

File1.txt has columns like this:

```
2011 332 09 13 055 129 ?
2011 332 12 26 082 102 ?
2011 334 00 27 042 104 ?
```

File2.txt has collumns like this:

```
2011 328 11 24  102534.03  41.898  142.639  38 6.2  51.84 282.43  59.62 543.77
2011 332 11 28  091311.34  -7.019  116.983 616 5.8  54.94 318.54 128.75 513.82
2011 332 11 28  122645.45  -5.480  153.733  25 6.1  81.93 304.06 101.83 736.05
2011 334 11 30  002706.99  15.455  118.999   9 6.0  41.71 301.99 104.00 468.19
```

if column1 of file1==column1 of file2 && column2 of file1== column2 of file2 && column3 of file1 == first 2 bits of column5 of file2 && column4 of file1== next 2 bits of column5 of file two then join those rows.

eg:

```
this line from file1 2011 332 09 13 055 129 ? 
this line from file2 2011 332 11 28  091311.34  -7.019  116.983 616 5.8  54.94 318.54 128.75    513.82
```

gives output:

```
2011 332 09 13 055 129 ?
11 28  091311.34  -7.019  116.983 616 5.8  54.94 318.54 128.75  513.82
```

Comment: you probably want to format your question a bit more carefully, it is difficult to read or understand the intent as it stands.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This sounds like a database question - have you tried finding text-file oriented database access tools?

Comment: Maybe this helps, if the text files are small: http://stackoverflow.com/q/778081/2277620